# Website or app recommendation for Visualising statistics concept, comparable to VISNOS mathematics

Tags: references

There is a great website for visualising basic mathematics concepts, namely [VISNOS](https://www.visnos.com/demos).
I am looking for similar *interactive* apps to visualise statistics basic concepts, especially how does the normal distribution connects or links with other distributions (students t distribution, chi square distribution etc) and how they relates to chi square testing, students t-test, etc. Testing. Will be greatly benifited if there are also interactive apps for understanding  corelations, regression analysis, ANOVA etc. and how does they work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have visited this meta post https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/what-is-our-stance-on-website-recommendation-questions before asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

As per commented by user @whuber in [another discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/should-we-have-some-interactive-games-or-tools-about-statistics-and-data-science), one such website is [Rossmanchance](http://www.rossmanchance.com/applets/).

Also [Artofstat](http://www.artofstat.com/webapps.html) has several tools.

[Whfreeman](http://bcs.whfreeman.com/webpub/statistics/ips9e/9781319013387/statisticalapplets/statisticalapplets.html) have a list of applets.